# google line chart with non equal distances on x axis

Tags: google-visualization

i have given points of 2 lines. The x values are non equaly spaced. What kind of visualization (google visualization api) can i use to display the lines without interpolation of the missing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [LineChart (Chart Types)](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/apis/chart/docs/gallery/line_charts.html#chart_types).
The ChartType cht=lxy is what you reqiure.

Comment: ok this helps. Is there a equivalent in google visualization api, or exist this type only in google chart api?